# UWP override style properties without loosing other property definitions

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I create an UWP App and define some styles like this:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" >
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange" />
<Setter Property="Margin" Value="12" />
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
```

So, all my TextBlocks are orange and have a margin of 12px. All fine. But now I want to define a second style for Headlines, which should be inherit the base style and just override the extra defined properties, like this:

```
  <Style x:Key="HeadlineStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">    
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="32" />
```

But if I do it this way, all other style definitions are gone (no margin, no coloring).

So how could I keep the base style?

In WPF I can use the x:Type attribute and just say

```
BasedOn="{StaticResource  {x:Type Button}}"
```

But x:Type are not available in UWP (and what I found it is no longer supported)

Comment: Name your customized style and then create an empty default style that is `BasedOn` it (and any number of other styles). Basically switch things around from your current approach.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT may as well put as answer and give them a tad more info. Although I'm sure this is probably a duplicate of another question somewhere, just didn't find an example.

Comment: do you mean something like that? `<Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource BasicTextBlockStyle}" /> ` It didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does exactly what you want:

```
<Grid.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="medium">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
  </Style>
  <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource medium}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
  </Style>
  <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="bigger" BasedOn="{StaticResource medium}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"/>
  </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
<StackPanel>
  <TextBlock Text="normal"/>
  <TextBlock Text="medium" Style="{StaticResource medium}"/>
  <TextBlock Text="bigger" Style="{StaticResource bigger}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

- The first TextBlock is 10-px orange
- The second TextBlock is 20-px orange
- The third TextBlock is 30-px orange

Comment: Okay, thanks for the example. I re-edited my code like your sample and now it works.